# Creating branch with capital first letter in VS Code

Tags: git

What was the exact solution?

I have created a branch `feature/ilink2/visits/101386-events-appointments`, but it was created with a capital F

```
Feature/ilink2/visits/101386-events-appointments
```

If I switch to my team mates branch that time also same happening it was creating the new one

Comment: You are on Windows, correct?